# Load data from local file on Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery table

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

here is the code taken from GitHub,
 to load data from the local file on Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery table (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/load_data_from_gcs.py)

```
    import argparse
    import uuid
    import pprint
    from google.cloud import bigquery

    dataset_name = 'test'
    table_name = 'partition1'
    source = "gs://a_eu/has/con/c-1489230000-8U3bTN.csv"
    format = 'CSV'

    def load_data_from_gcs(dataset_name, table_name, source):
        bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
        dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
        table = dataset.table(table_name)
        job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

        job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(
            job_name, table, source)

        job.source_format = format
        job.begin()
        print job.begin
        job.result()
        print job.result

        print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(
            job.output_rows, dataset_name, table_name))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description=__doc__,
            formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
        parser.add_argument('dataset_name')
        parser.add_argument('table_name')
        parser.add_argument('source')

        args = parser.parse_args()

        load_data_from_gcs(
            args.dataset_name,
            args.table_name,
            args.source)

load_data_from_gcs(dataset_name, table_name, source)
```

When I run it there is the following error:

```
usage: partition2.py [-h] dataset_name table_name source
partition2.py: error: too few arguments
```

Could you please give me a hint, what's this problem about?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Python script is expecting parameters, in particular `dataset_name` `table_name` and `source`. You are not passing any parameters to the script.

I notice you've tried hard coding these parameters. So, in that case, just remove the cli params if you don't need them or mark them optional.